# Null service response using mock test

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking

I have a service that find a object in the repository and return one attribute of the object.
I want try test service mocking access to repository, but when i call the service method return null.

My service:

```
@Service
public class MyService{

    public Object getModuleObj(String id, String module) {
        Object repObj = Repository.findOne(id,module);
        return repObj.getModule();
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
    public class ApiTest {

        @MockBean
        public MyRepository repository;

        @MockBean
        private MyService service;

        @Test
        public void testGetObjectOfRepo() throws Exception {
            Object obj = new Object();
            Module mod = new Module();
            mod.setId("6");
            mod.setModule("test");
            obj.add(mod);

            /** mock repository response **/
            Mockito.when(repository.findOne("6","test")).thenReturn(obj);

            /** invoke service method**/
            String module= "test";
            /** serviceResponse return null **/
            Module serviceResponse = this.service.getModuleObj("6","test");
            Assert.assertEquals(mod, serviceResponse);
        }


        }
```

Comparison between objects fail because serviceResponse is null. It's correct as i'm mocking the repository?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock static methods with Mockito. If you want to test the `getModuleObj` method, you will have to extract the static call to non-static method like this:

```
@Service
public class MyService{

    public Object getModuleObj(String id, String module) {
        Object repObj = this.findOne(id,module);
        return repObj.getModule();
    }

    Object findOne(String id, String module){
        return Repository.findOne(id,module);
    }
}
```

And then you can test the rest of the method by creating a spy:

```
@Test
public void testGetObjectOfRepo() throws Exception {
    MyService service = spy(MyService.class);
    Object obj = new Object();
    //initialize the obj
    doReturn(obj).when(service.findOne(anyString(), anyString()));

    Module serviceResponse = service.getModuleObj("6","test");
    //asertions
}
```

I'm not sure if that's your intention, because your code seems a bit obfuscated. I really hope you didn't create a class `Object`, because `java.lang.Object` does not have method `add`

Answer (score 0):

I was resolve my cuestion using ReflectionTestUtils for inject repository access in the service. 
The code of the test class:

```
@Test
public void testMyService() throws Exception {
Object obj = new Object();
            Module mod = new Module();
            mod.setId("6");
            mod.setModule("test");
            obj.add(mod);

            /** mock repository response **/
            Mockito.when(repository.findOne("6","test")).thenReturn(obj);
            /** inject mock repository in service*/
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this.service, null, "filterRepository", repository, null); 
//Asserts
}
```